# printf output is not showed in google colab

Tags: kernel, output, printf, google-colaboratory, pycuda

I run a small kernel to use "printf" function in pycuda in **google colab**, I do not receive any error but I don't observe any output. I used **Cuda.Context.synchronize()** but it doesn't have an effect on my result!!

Answer (score -1):

You should add one line of code to your program:

cudaDeviceSynchronize();

The code just forces the printf()s to flush.